# Standard delegates in C#

Tags: c#, list, delegates

There are some Delegates predefined in C#

I know these:

```
EventHandler // Default event callbacks
EventHandler<T> // Default event callbacks with custom parameter (inheriting from EventArgs)
Action // Function without return value and without parameter
Action<T1, T2, T3, T4> // Function without return value and 1-4 parameters
Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult> // Methos with 0-4 parameters and one result type
Predicate<T> // equivalent to Func<T, bool>
```

There are many more for special cases and generated form parts of the framework, but these are often good to use in self written code.

If you know some more useful add them. Otherwise this is answered.

Comment: Would like to reopen this and convert it to a community wiki page.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They're not predefined in C#. They're defined by the *framework*.

The `Action` and `Func` delegate families are wider than you've shown - they go up to

```
Action<T1, T2, T3, T4>
```

and

```
Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>
```

Another common-ish one in .NET 2.0 for list manipulation (before LINQ) is `Predicate<T>`.

For working with threads:

```
ThreadStart
ParameterizedThreadStart
WaitCallback
TimerCallback
AsyncCallback
```

Comment: It does make you wonder though. If generics and Func / Action were available in 1.0, would we have any other delegate types?

Comment: It's an interesting question. I rather like Predicate<T> as a more meaningful name than Func<T, bool> for instance - if it weren't for the overloads of Where etc to take Func<T, int, bool> it would be a better fit for LINQ. Specifying type arguments everywhere can hurt readability.

Answer (score 5):

I like to use `Predicate<T>` which is equivalent to `Func<T, bool>`

Answer (score 2):

Goto [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) Search for **System.MulticastDelegate** and check the derived types. You will get list of all the Delegates you are looking for.

Comment: Well, that gives a complete list of delegates. It doesn't give the most useful or important ones, which is what the OP was after I think.

Answer (score 2):

I've also come across

```
Comparison<T>
```

in the

```
List.Sort(Comparison<T>)
```

generic method. I suppose this is now equivalent to:

```
Func<T1, T2, int>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `WaitCallback` and `ThreadStart` often enough for them to get a mention.

If you know the *signature* of the delegate you're after, but you don't know if there's an *existing* delegate with that signature that you can use, you can follow [these instructions](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/01/consolidating-delegates-with-reflector.html) on my blog to find one.

Comment: Link appears not to be valid any more.

Answer (score 0):

System.Windows.ValidateValueCallback which represents a method used as a callback that validates the effective value of a dependency property.

Read More: [MSDN: ValidateValueCallback Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.validatevaluecallback.aspx)