# Default delegate in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

What is the name of the default delegate in C# which takes no parameters and returns void? I remember there existed such a delegate but I don't remember its name.

Comment: What is the name of that seach engine that you can use to find stuff with? ;) http://www.google.se/search?q=c%23+delegate+no+parameters+returns+void

Comment: @Guffa: Which now happens to point back to this question...

Comment: @davidg: That usually happens after only a few minutes, regardless of whether there are any useful answers or not. Just because something appears in a google result isn't any guarantee that there is any useful information there...

Answer (score 14):

Prior to .NET 3.5, it was fairly common to declare your own. Now, `Action` is a good candidate, but `ThreadStart` was commonly used (fairly confusingly), or `MethodInvoker` *if* you were already referencing winforms.

A quick test (note, running in .NET 4.0, using just some libraries - so not exhaustive):

```
var qry = from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
          from type in asm.GetTypes()
          where type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate))
          let method = type.GetMethod("Invoke")
          where method != null && method.ReturnType == typeof(void)
          && method.GetParameters().Length == 0
          orderby type.AssemblyQualifiedName
          select type.AssemblyQualifiedName;
foreach (var name in qry) Console.WriteLine(name);
```

shows some more candidates:

```
System.Action, mscorlib...
System.CrossAppDomainDelegate, mscorlib...
System.IO.Pipes.PipeStreamImpersonationWorker, System.Core...
System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler+WriteBack, System.Core...
System.Net.UnlockConnectionDelegate, System...
System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.CrossContextDelegate, mscorlib...
System.Threading.ThreadStart, mscorlib...
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+AboutBoxDelegate, System.Windows.Forms...
System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker, System.Windows.Forms...
```

Comment: I vote for alternating between AxHost.AboutBoxDelegate and LambdaCompiler.WriteBack. I shall start ripped uses of "Action" out of my code forthwith.

Answer (score 8):

There are several such delgates, but I think you are looking for [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx). One other option is [`MethodInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) (in System.Windows.Forms).

Comment: Its only for version 3.5 and above? Are there any for 2.0?

Comment: @Tuxedo: `MethodInvoker` has been around since 1.1. If you want something in the `System` namespace there is the `CrossAppDomainDelegate`, but its name is so specific so it will probably seem a bit weird for more general purpose use.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for "[Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371054/uses-of-action-delegate-in-c)".

Some related reading:

- [Standard delegates in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729912/standard-delegates-in-c)
- [Action Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)
- [Uses of Action delegate in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371054/uses-of-action-delegate-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

*I may be interpreting your question differently to everyone else, but:*

If you are thinking of the delegate to use for event handling, convention is to use [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx). This delegate doesn't take 'no' parameters, but it is essentially information-less.

Answer (score 2):

In .net 2.0 the `MethodInvoker` delegate is the recomended way. It is the most generic. As it's name suggest it invokes a method. Others might have the same properties you described but they have different name that suggest other usages or very specific usages in specific areas.